# How to install InfluxDB and Grafana?

Tags: software-installation, database

How to install InfluxDB and Grafana on my Raspberry Pi (1) / Raspbian Wheezy?
As new release as possible.

Comment: Check out [Aymerick’s guide](http://www.aymerick.com/2015/10/07/influxdb-telegraf-grafana-raspberry-pi.html) for the RPi2.

Comment: For influxDB you can follow the instructions here: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-influxdb/
For Grafana here: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-grafana/

Answer (score 3):

I tried the same a few days ago on my RPi3 with the newest Raspbian Jessie (2016-03-18). But most of the tutorials online are kinda old and didn't seem to to work for me. (Like the answer from Daniel which is already outdated and the build of InfluxDB always failed)

I finally found this tutorial for InfluxDB, Telegraf and Grafana on a RPi2 on [Padcom's blog](http://padcom13.blogspot.co.at/2015/12/influxdb-telegraf-and-grafana-on.html). He provides precompiled packages witch shortens the installation process to ~10min and also worked without problems on my RPi3.